# What should I do to render sum of array objects values from API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In `this.state.companiesIncome`, I have an array of 50 objects that have a `{value and date}`, but when I'm trying to `console.log(this.state.companiesIncome[2].value)` I'm receiving `TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null`.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './CompanyTotalIncome.css'
import axios from 'axios'

class CompanyIncome extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      companyID: props.companyID,
      companiesIncome: null
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get(`https://API/${this.state.companyID}`).then(res => {
      this.setState({ companiesIncome: res.data.incomes })
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.companiesIncome[2].value)
    return (
      <>
        <th>Total income</th>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default CompanyIncome
```

Comment: `componentWillMount` is a lifecycle method that will get called when your component mounts, however, your API call is asynchronous, so by the time you get to `render`, your `API` may still be going and your `state` is `null`, so you need to handle this better, for example render a list of items only  `if (this.state.companiesIncome && this.state.companiesIncome.length > 0)`

Answer (score 1):

`componentWillMount` has been deprecated.

Use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount` to make the AJAX Call.

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get(`https://API/${this.state.companyID}`).then(res => {
    this.setState({ companiesIncome: res.data.incomes });
  });
}
```

And place a check before using `this.state.companiesIncome`

```
this.state.companiesIncome && console.log(this.state.companiesIncome[2].value);
```

You're seeing the error before the `axios.get` will fire an AJAX call which is asynchronous by nature. And your `render` method will anyway get called before `componentDidMount`. So by the time the log gets called, `this.state.companiesIncome` would still be `null`.

Once `componentDidMount` is called, the API data is fetched and `setState` is called, it will trigger a re-render and the `render` method will be called again. This time with `companiesData` set. So it would work as expected.

> Here's a [**Working Code Demo Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-get-data-from-api) for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

Because at the initial state your companiesIncome is null, companiesIncome[2] will throw an error. To avoid this, you can do the following:

```
this.state.companiesIncome && this.state.companiesIncome[2].value
```

This way, it will be printed only if you have a valid companiesIncome value. To improve it a bit you can also write:

```
(this.state.companiesIncome && this.state.companiesIncome.length >= 2) && this.state.companiesIncome[2].value
```

If you only want to log it to the console, do the following:

```
console.log(this.state.companiesIncome ? this.state.companiesIncome[2].value : 'companiesIncome is null');
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that React starts rendering at the beginning. You can look in [JSFiddleExample](https://jsfiddle.net/alexaaaant/t4nre20b/1/), in the console you will see a render at the beginning, then componentDidMount. Therefore, you must add validation. `this.state.companiesIncome! == null`. When you will change the state in the componentDidMount, the render starts again with your data.
You can read about React Lifecycle in [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)